# Convert list of ticker symbols into list in Python

Tags: python, list, text-files, spaces, stocks

I need to convert a list of ticker symbols:
T
GOOG
KO
PEP
as examples in a a text file to a python list: ['T','GOOG','KO',PEP']. However, the current code I'm using keeps adding a space after each symbol yielding: ['T ','GOOG ','KO ',PEP '] instead. How can I get the tickers without spaces?

```
stocks = open('C:\Model\Stocks\official.txt', 'r').read()
print stocks.split('\n')
```

Comment: Apparently the bimbos at Standard & Poors decided to put a nice little space after each symbol on the excel file. I guess I need to figure out how to remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest strip function, which maps the result:

```
>>> a = ["A ", "B ", "C "]
>>> a
['A ', 'B ', 'C ']
>>> a = map(lambda x: x.strip(), a)
>>> a
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

In your example:

```
a = stocks.split('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
stocks = open('C:\Model\Stocks\official.txt', 'r').read()
lstStripped =  [x.strip() for x in stocks.split('\n')]
print lstStripped
```